# Using a closure in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm trying to implement the code from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219924/idiomatic-jquery-delayed-event-only-after-a-short-pause-in-typing-e-g-timew) in coffeescript.

This is what I've got but it doesn't work.

```
class SomeClass

    initialize: ->

      target = view.$('#finder')

      typewatch = do ->
        timer = 0;
        (callback, ms) ->
          clearTimeout timer
          timer = setTimeout callback, ms

      target.keyup =>
        typewatch @someMethod(target.val()), 1000


    someMethod: (arg) ->
      // do something
```

`someMethod` gets called without any delay. It seems like setTimeout isn't being called at all.

Comment: Try `timer = setTimeout callback, 1000`

Comment: @elclanrs: That makes a lot of sense and I've update the code accordingly, but my problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@someMethod()` grammar does invoke the method immediately.

If you want to "store" a method invocation (roughly, method+`this`+arguments) in a variable and call it later, use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). e.g. `typewatch @someMethod.bind(@, target.val()), 1000`

BTW as elclanrs mentioned, the `setTimeout (->callback)` part won't really execute callback.