# How to represent and autocomplete JSON of suggestions based on Google Books API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, google-api

This question is based on [Results of recommendations using Google Books API are irrelevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842748/results-of-recommendations-using-google-books-api-are-irrelevant) .

In general I am building possibility for user to add the book to his collection.
For this purpose user searches through books using information from Google Books. But without suggestions based on what user types in the search field, it would be extremely uncomfortable.

At this point now we get jSON text of book suggestions, but I do not really understand how to represent this? So how to create a normal list of that JSON and create possibility for user to choose one of those recommendations,so that each of them will be autocompleted in the search field on click?

```js
var requestUrl = "https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&ds=bo&q=";
var xhr;

$(document).on("input", "#query", function () {
    typewatch(function () {
      
        var queryTerm = $("#query").val();
        $("#indicator").show();
        if (xhr != null) xhr.abort();
        xhr = $.ajax({
            url: requestUrl + queryTerm,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (response) {
            
                $("#indicator").hide();
                $("#output").html(response);
               
            }
        });
    }, 500);
});




$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#indicator").hide();
});
var typewatch = (function () {
    var timer = 0;
    return function (callback, ms) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type=text id="query" placeholder="Start typing..." /><span id="indicator"></span>
    <div style="width:600px;height:700px;padding-bottom:100px;position:relative;background:#6c94b8;" id="output"></div>
    <label for="query" style="position:relative;margin-left:100px;margin-top:100px;">Tags: </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are after:
 https://www.librarieshacked.org/tutorials/autocompletewithapi

```
$(document).ready(function () {  // only begin once page has loaded
    $("#txtBookSearch").autocomplete({ // attach auto-complete functionality to textbox
        // define source of the data
        source: function (request, response) {
            // url link to google books, including text entered by user (request.term)
            var booksUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?printType=books&q=" + encodeURIComponent(request.term);
            $.ajax({
                url: booksUrl,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data.items, function (item) {
                        if (item.volumeInfo.authors && item.volumeInfo.title && item.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers && item.volumeInfo.publishedDate)
                        {
                            return {
                                // label value will be shown in the suggestions
                                label: item.volumeInfo.title + ', ' + item.volumeInfo.authors[0] + ', ' + item.volumeInfo.publishedDate,
                                // value is what gets put in the textbox once an item selected
                                value: item.volumeInfo.title,
                                // other individual values to use later
                                title: item.volumeInfo.title,
                                author: item.volumeInfo.authors[0],
                                isbn: item.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers,
                                publishedDate: item.volumeInfo.publishedDate,
                                image: (item.volumeInfo.imageLinks == null ? "" : item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail),
                                description: item.volumeInfo.description,
                            };
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            // what to do when an item is selected
            // first clear anything that may already be in the description
            $('#divDescription').empty();
            // we get the currently selected item using ui.item
            // show a pic if we have one
            if (item.image != '')
            {
                $('#divDescription').append('<img src="' + ui.item.image + '" style="float: left; padding: 10px;">');
            }
            // and title, author, and year
            $('#divDescription').append('<p><b>Title:</b> ' + ui.item.title  + '</p>');
            $('#divDescription').append('<p><b>Author:</b> ' + ui.item.author  + '</p>');
            $('#divDescription').append('<p><b>First published year:</b> ' + ui.item.publishedDate  + '</p>');          
            // and the usual description of the book
            $('#divDescription').append('<p><b>Description:</b> ' + ui.item.description  + '</p>');
            // and show the link to oclc (if we have an isbn number)
            if (ui.item.isbn && ui.item.isbn[0].identifier)
            {
                $('#divDescription').append('<P><b>ISBN:</b> ' + ui.item.isbn[0].identifier + '</p>');
                $('#divDescription').append('<a href="http://www.worldcat.org/isbn/' + ui.item.isbn[0].identifier + '" target="_blank">View item on worldcat</a>');
            }
        },
        minLength: 2 // set minimum length of text the user must enter
    });
});
```